# Why isn't Coq recognizing compiled libraries?

Tags: sublimetext3, coq

I'm trying to get Coq working as a plugin for Sublime Text 3 on MacOS. I have everything working save for code that requires import statements.

The exact same code works perfectly when run in CoqIDE (which runs Coqc version 8.9), but when I try to run from Coqc verion 8.8 (homebrew install), when I reach my statement:

```
From LF Require Export Basics.
```

it throws the error:

```
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix <> and prefix LF.
```

When I remove `From LF` I get:

`Basics.vo contains library LF.Basics and not library Basics`

which indicates (at least to me) that the libraries are, indeed, compiling and making correctly, and something else is wrong.

Here are the commands that I run:

```
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o CoqMakefile
make -f CoqMakefile -B
```

My _CoqProject looks like this:

```
-R . LF
Basics.v
Induction.v
```

Anyone have any ideas or any experience with this?

Comment: Do you know what command you are using to run `coqc`? Any reason for preferring 8.8 to 8.9?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim The main reason that I'm using 8.8 is because it is what is installed by Homebrew by default. I tried uninstalling it and installing 8.9 via opam, but I ran into a seemingly well-known problem with installing the ocaml "num" library that I was unable to resolve with any of the given solutions. In terms of what command I'm using to run coqc: I have no idea. How would I figure this out?

Comment: You can figure it out by running `make VERBOSE=1`.  What is the output when you do this?